# Spring boot Transaction id

Tags: java, transactions

I have the following use case -

1. The user fills up a form.
2. The spring boot backend code calls multiples services before pushing the user data to the database.
3. The database takes more than 10 secs to commit the details

Since the whole process takes time, I want to return a transaction id to the user immediately after he fills up the form. The user can check the status later using the same transaction Id.

Does spring boot provide any feature to achieve this?

Answer (score 0):

You can try to use @Async even though it doesn't give u future but the tx and Thread executor is been taken care, however the request timeout should be increased to void timeouts.

https://spring.io/guides/gs/async-method/

Answer (score 0):

You would need to implement some reactive approach for this, Spring's framework for this is WebFlux take a look at https://docs.spring.io/spring-framework/docs/5.0.0.BUILD-SNAPSHOT/spring-framework-reference/html/web-reactive.html.